# How to avoid page flashing in Next.js? (Static page showed before script that decide what to render is executed)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, ssg

I have a Next.js app that have index page that uses SSG (static page generation) and pages that contains subdomain in url.

Expected behaviour - when url is *hostname.com* I want to render main static page, but when url is *company1.hostname.com* I want to render content with company1 data.

The problem - when I go to ***company1.hostname.com*** first of all I getting main static page, then script which decide what to render depends on subdomain executing and if we have a subdomain - we show page with data for subdomain. It causes that content is flashing (first show main page then immediately show subdomain page).

My main page code:

```
const HomePage: NextPage<Props> = ({ content }) => {
  const { attributes } = content;
  const subdomain = getSubdomain();
  return (
    <>
      <SEO />
      <div className="m-auto max-w-7xl">
        {subdomain ? (
          <SubdomainDataComponent subdomain={subdomain} />
        ) : (
          <>
            <MainPage />
          </>
        )}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

 export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async () => {
   const content = await import(`../content/pages/${'home'}.md`);

   return { props: { content: content.default } };
 };


export default HomePage;
```

How I can avoid flashing of page?
And is it possible to retrieve url data (subdomain, hostname, etc) in getStaticProps function?

Comment: You should use middlewares : https://github.com/vercel/examples/tree/main/edge-functions/hostname-rewrites. And no you cannot  retrieve url data in `getStaticProps`